# How can I get token Id from erc721 contract address?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, erc-721

I extracted the contracted address from a transaction hash.Now I want know its tokenID , is there any method through web3.py that could help ,or any other way in which I can get tokenID of that contract address.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood ERC-721. An ERC-721 contract can contain multiple tokens (denoted by token id). If you want let's say the `tokenURI` of a particular tokenID, you can call `tokenURI(tokenId)` to get the URI of that particular token. That said, the contract can also contain just 1 token. So get the number of tokens it contains, in certain contracts you can check via `totalSupply()` function. But it's not guaranteed that all ERC-721 contracts will have `totalSupply` implemented.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes you can check if it's an ERC721](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706835/how-to-check-if-the-token-on-opensea-is-erc721-or-erc1155-using-node-js) , it has nothing to do with TokenIDs though. The other answer explains why.

Answer (score 1):

`ERC721` contract allows to `mint` a token. This token would have a token id, not the contract itself.

There are several options to get token ids from `ERC721` contract.

`ERC721` standard allows to have Enumerable interface which gives access to token ids. Although, there is well known security attack on its concept and implementation by overusing `balanceOf()` call (or may be something different).

Another option is query events for this contract and search of returned results for pair user-tokenId.

Finally we can store a minted token id in the separate special storage.

I prefer the last one. It is not issue when you are developer of the contract.

Comment: Please note ```Enumerable``` usage not only open a security risk, but also significantly increase cost of usage which looks like a one of major issues of using blockchain technology in production.

Answer (score 0):

I basically wont to identify whether the contract is of ERC721 through its address.

Therefore I thought using token id as reference like if contract has token id it will be of ERC721.

Is there any other way that could help?